# Resizing image to square

Tags: python, image, resize, python-imaging-library

I have a lot of different sized images, from 1100x200 to 100x20. Now, I would like to resize alle this images to a square with an equal size (e.g. 256x256).

I would like to resize a picture like this one:

[image: original]

I would like to get a new square image like this one:

[image: square]

I tried this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
original_image = Image.open(r"path\to\images\*.png")
size = (256, 256)
fit_and_resized_image = ImageOps.fit(original_image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Instead of the desired square image, I get an image like this one:

[image: square]

Unfortunately, it is a cropped image with the original ratios instead of the type of image I want.

Comment: PIL has a [resize](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-resize-method/) function. I haven't tested it, but it should do what you want. Just do something like `new_image = original_image.resize(size)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be doing a lot of image processing, OpenCV is a great option.

```
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('path/to/file.png')
print (img.shape)
size = (256, 256)

img2 = cv2.resize(img, size)
print (img2.shape)  # (256, 256)

cv2.imshow('img1', img)
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **thumbnail**

```
from PIL import Image
original_image = Image.open(r"path\to\images\*.png")
size = (256, 256)
original_image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```